# Install older version of protobuf via vcpkg

Tags: protobuf-c, vcpkg

I installed protobuf via vcpkg `vcpkg install protobuf:x64-windows`. Apparently it installs the latest version (3.6.1). For the project I need version<=3.5.1. Is there any way to install it using vcpkg? For now I just built 3.5.1 using cmake but project looking for protobuf using path to vcpkg and I don't really know if I'm allowed to change the code.

Comment: Ok, for those who encountered with same issue you can solve it by using checkout to the working commit of vcpkg with necessary protobuf.

Answer (score 5):

To have a specific version of a package in `vcpkg`, you need to checkout at the appropriate point in time in the [`vcpk` repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg).

1. Go to your git installed `vcpk` folder.
2. Identify the commit matching the version of `protobuf` you're looking for.

The following line color-codes the commit history to make it more
readable and pipe it with `grep` to identify `protobuf` related commits.

`git log --color=always --pretty='%Cred%h%Creset -%C(auto)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%ad)' --date=short | grep --color=never protobuf`

You'll find a line like `b1fea4588 - [protobuf] update to 3.5.1 (2018-01-31)`.
(The commit hash/message may have changed if the history has been rewritten.)

3. Checkout the commit of interest :
   `git checkout b1fea4588`
4. Run `vcpkg install protobuf`

The issue of package version management is very active on `vcpkg` repo. Check [Issue #3592](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/3592)

Answer (score 0):

According to the solution found on the [github/vcpkg/issues](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/21357#issuecomment-968325176), you can modify `<VCPKG_ROOT>/ports/<packet_name>/vcpkg.json` and change the `version` of the package to the old version.
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Use a new feature (June 2019): **ports overlay** https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/specifications/ports-overlay.md

Here is an example. The version of packet is hardcoded in file:

```
<VCPKG_ROOT>/ports/<packet_name>/CONTROL
```

Thus it's bound to the commit of vckpg. But you can override packet version with the following command

```
vcpkg --overlay-ports="/some/path/to/the_versions" install protobuf:x64-windows
```

The directory should contain packet specs:

```
/some/path/to/the_versions/protobuf/CONTROL
/some/path/to/the_versions/<packet_2_name>/CONTROL
/some/path/to/the_versions/<packet_3_name>/CONTROL
```

Usually, I just copy packet specs from the commit I was initially developing my project for. Hope this helps!